# How to determine if user’s got any Apple Watch from iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, watchkit, watchos

as question says my goal is to know if the user’s got any Apple Watch. `WCSession.isSupported()` just returns me if the iPhone supports an Apple Watch, not if the user got it or not;
`session.isPaired` just returns me if the Watch is currently paired to iPhone, but returns me `false`  both the user doesn’t have any Watch and the user’s got it but turned off.

Is there any API for my goal?
Thank you

Comment: This maybe: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck ?

Comment: @koen how this could be useful? can you provide me an example, please?

Comment: To be honest, I have not used that API, but from glancing at it, thought it could be useful when identifying devices.